# Select a DATE that lies any 3 months ago

Tags: mysql, date, intervals

I'm trying to get a resultset from my MySQL database that lists all accounts that had a start date that lies any quarter ago (so either 3, 6, 9, 12 etc. months ago). The following query works for a single quarter:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `date_start` FROM `accounts`
WHERE `account_status_id`=2
AND DATE_FORMAT(`date_start`, '%m%d') = DATE_FORMAT(
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 QUARTER), '%m%d'
);
```

This lists everything that started exactly 3 months ago, which is good. But I would also like any multiplication of 3 months ago (so 6, 9 etc.) to be selected as well. How would I do that?

Comment: Is there any limit of multiples or 9,12,15 ..... so on ?

Comment: @dianuj Preferably not, I could of course add an `OR` clause and add all possible months it may go back, but I'd prefer a solution that determines the period on-the-fly, so the end-user is not limited to a year or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the modulo operator.

This is just off the top of my head, so it might not be completely correct, but it should be enough to get you on the right track. The mod operator will return 0, in this case, for any multiple of three months back in time.

On second thought, you should probably use `MONTH()` and `DAY()` instead of `DATE_FORMAT`

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `date_start` FROM `accounts`
WHERE `account_status_id`=2
AND DAY(`date_start`) = DAY(NOW())
AND ((( MONTH(NOW()) - MONTH(`date_start`)) mod 3) = 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `date_start`
FROM `accounts`
WHERE `account_status_id`=2
and dayofmonth(date_start) = dayofmonth(curdate())
and month(date_start) % 3 = month(CURDATE()) % 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider that "exactly three months ago" might be a bit, uh, unspecified. If it's May 31, what's "Three months ago"? February 31???? March 3????? ;)

So, it maybe better to use "90 days ago" or "12 weeks ago" which would both use similar mod methods. Both of these have very precise definitions. The months thing will have you banging your head against the table. However, it may be the spec, and you have no option. In that case, be sure to test against the various end-of-month cases.

Comment: Good advice, I'll be sure to run some tests for these scenario's.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
   SELECT `id`, `name`, `date_start` FROM `accounts`
   WHERE MONTH(`date_start`)- MONTH(NOW())  IN (-3,-6,-9,0,3,6,9)
```

if you want also check the exact day then add this

```
   AND  DAY(`date_start`) = DAY(NOW())
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f4424/4)

it could be more simpler but the idea is this.